# Create short url for document in sharepoint 2013 document library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, managed-navigation

I want to create short URL for the document in SharePoint 2013 document library.

**Eg.** `www.example.com/en/Documents/TestNew.pdf` to `www.example.com/en/TestNew`

I have tried to do using Managed Metadata Navigation but not succeed.

Please share with me steps to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried document link content type that can be used to create shortcuts to documents?

Comment: Have you tried using any available plugins such as SharePoint ShortUrl? (https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104368123&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&appredirect=false)

Answer (score 0):

What is the link used for? Can't you just hyperlink the document using an anchor like below example?

```
<a href="www.example.com/en/Documents/TestNew.pdf">Test New</a>
```